# How to find how many HDDs are present in a NAS?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, nas, mirroring

I'm logged into the web interface of a NAS made by LG Electronics. It is obviously running some Linux version :

```
Linux LG-NAS-N1T1 2.6.30-nt1 #130 Sun Nov 28 15/31/54 KST 2010 armv5tel GNU/Linux REV.37
```

I'd like to know how many harddisks there are in the NAS because I paid for a NAS setup with 3TB (I don't know if it was supposed to be a setup with two or three drives) but then the "admin" disappeared.

In the *LG Network Storage / Log / Self-diagnosis* menu, I find also these infos:

```
ODD ID F/W /dev/md1 /mnt/disk/volume1 No RAID
Bay1 ID Capa Temp SMART Hitachi HDS72101HDS72101 1000G 48C
```

I put the emphasis on the fact that it *is* written HDS72101HDS72101 twice.

However one can also see "No RAID" on the line above and "Bay1".

Does this mean there is only one harddisk in that NAS device?

It's the same in the *Status / Hard Disk menu*, I see only one bay:

```
B1  Hitachi  HDS72101HDS72101
```

My question to anyone who has a NAS (and ideally a LG Network Storage NAS with the same kind of web interface) is simple: are there circumstances under which two (or more) drives can be reported as part of the same "bay"?  Or is it supposed to be "one drive, one bay"?

I take it that to be sure I could open the NAS but I really don't want to mess it up, especially if the mirrored setup I asked/paid for hasn't been delivered (I can't really afford to lose what's there and I'm doing a network copy of as many files as I can as I type this).

Comment: The [specifications](http://www.lg.com/us/data-storage/lg-N1T1) say "500GB / 1TB (Up to 2TB Total)", so I don't see how a supported setup could have 3 TB.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: I'm googling and it's worse than that... Apparently it's a "NAS" which cannot even have two drives: it seems to be an N1T1 and I find an article saying *" the N1T1 only has one 1 TB internal hard drive. There's therefore no scope for mirroring the contents of the main drive onto a second internal drive"*. So you cannot mirror at all. Is it common for NAS devices to have no possibility of mirroring?

Comment: NAS means just Network Attached Storage, there's no requirement to have advanced features like mirroring (e.g. RAID 1) or stripping (e.g. RAID 0). By the way, you might like the article ["Big data meets big storage: an in-depth look at Isilon’s scale-out storage solution"](http://arstechnica.com/business/2011/05/isilon-overview/) from Ars Technica if you want to see how advanced NAS devices look like.